# I run into a segmentation fault with one of the test cases. The test cases are hidden

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqUcu.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpN3u.jpg)

The image below is the problem with sample input and output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovOpr.jpg)

I run into a segmentation fault with one of the test cases. The test cases are hidden.
5 out of 6 test cases work but for one of the test cases I get a segmentation fault.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


//utility function to return maximum of two integers
int max(int x, int y) {
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
}

//function to return maximum profit
int fractionalKnapsack(int capacity, int weight[], int vec[], int num) {
    int wt, i;
    int K[num+1][capacity+1];
//iterate nested loop
    for (i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        for (wt = 0; wt <= capacity; wt++) {
//base case
            if (i == 0 || wt == 0)
                K[i][wt] = 0;
//otherwise if
            else if (weight[i - 1] <= wt)
                K[i][wt] = max(vec[i - 1] + K[i - 1][wt - weight[i - 1]], K[i - 1][wt]);
//otherwise
            else
                K[i][wt] = K[i - 1][wt];
        }
    }
    return K[num][capacity];
}

//driver code
int main() {
    int capacity,num;
//input knapsac capacity and number of objects
    cin >> capacity>>num;
    int vec[num], weight[num];
//input weight and value
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        cin >> weight[i]>>vec[i];
    }
//print result
    cout<< fractionalKnapsack(capacity, weight, vec, num)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if `num` is 0? I didn't check the logic but you should take care of it.

Comment: `i <= num`? `wt <= capacity` and not `i < num`? `wt < capacity`? Didn't read much the code, but this sounds suspicious...

Comment: First thing you should do is figure out which line of code causes the segmentation fault.  You can do that with a debugger, or by inserting debug-prints at various places until you narrow the location down (based on which debug-prints get printed before the crash and which do not).  Once you know for certain which line is the offending line, you can start examining that line to determine what it is doing wrong -- dereferencing an invalid pointer, or passing an invalid index into an array-lookup, are both common reasons for a line of code to cause a segfault.

Comment: What about vec[i-1] and K[i-1]when you start i at 0 is that really your intention?

Comment: I got feedback saying that the failed test case requires a lot of memory. Am I not using memory efficiently or something?

Comment: Once I custom input more than 18 objects, it writes “truncated.”